# Query about TrafficModeType & departure time

Tags: here-api

While going through the calculateroute(routing) API, noticed that when "traffic" is set as "enabled", "departure" parameter must also be provided:

*https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html#type-traffic-mode*

Following point is highlighted in the documentation when traffic is set as enabled:

**"No departure time provided: This behavior is deprecated and will return error in the future."**

Thus when I need to calculate time to travel from point A to B now(say by car) and with traffic as enabled, I need to also provide "departure" parameter with value as "now"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats right. You need to provide departure=now explicitly if you want to calculate the route based on current traffic conditions.

departure - Time when travel is expected to start. Traffic speed and incidents are taken into account when calculating the route (note that in case of a past departure time the historical traffic is limited to one year). You can use now to specify the current time. Specify either departure or arrival, not both. Type: xs:dateTime.

Example: departure=2018-07-04T17:00:00+02

When the optional timezone offset is not specified time is assumed to be local.